# How to make a circular UIView with an angular gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I need to make a view like

[image]

It is a circular segment, that has to have an angular gradient and rounded caps.

I need to know how to make angular gradient as shown on image.

Comment: Could you show us what have you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how I'd go about doing it.**

1. Create a `CALayer` to draw your 'background' for the loader. Unfortunately, there's no built in way of creating an angle gradient in Core Animation or Core Graphics. You'll either have to use a linear gradient with a `CAGradientLayer`, or have a look at [AngleGradientLayer](https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer).
2. Create a `CAShapeLayer` to define your circular arc. You will then want to create an arc path using a `UIBezierPath`'s [`+bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) method. You can then assign this path to the `CAShapeLayer`'s [`path`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/path) property.
3. You will then want to configure the stroking of the `CAShapeLayer`. You will want to set the [`lineWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/lineWidth) to the width of your stroke and set the [`lineCap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/lineCap) property to `kCALineCapRound`.
4. Assign your `CAShapeLayer` to the [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask) property of your background `CALayer`. This will mask the 'background' of your loader to the stroked path.
5. Add your background `CALayer` [as a sublayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/addSublayer:) to a `UIView`'s [`layer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer). (Or create a subclass of `UIView` and `CALayer` and [return your custom layer class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW24) in the view's [`+layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/layerClass) method)
6. Animate using a `CABasicAnimation` of the [`strokeStart`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/strokeStart) and [`strokeEnd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/strokeEnd) properties on the `CAShapeLayer`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using the UIBezierPath class. Specifically the addArcWithCenter function:

```
let line = UIBezierPath()
line.addArcWithCenter(centerPoint, radius: curveRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
color.setStroke()
line.stroke()
```

centerPoint, curveRadius, startAngle, and endAngle are all set ahead of time.

Color is a UIColor and is used to give the line color.